# How to set the AD Client Certificate Authentication using DSC

Tags: powershell

I want to set the Active Directory Client Certificate Authentication to TRUE for a web server using Desired State Configuration (DSC).

I want to use the xWebAdministration cmdlet for this.

The IIS path for setting the value is:
system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication

I already have this script, but the value hasn't been set correctly:

```
# Client Certificate Mapping Authentication should be present
        WindowsFeature ActiveDirectoryClientCertificateAuthentication
        {
            Name        = "Web-Cert-Auth"
            Ensure      = "Present"
            DependsOn   = "[WindowsFeature]IIS"
        }

        # Client Certificate Mapping Authentication should be present
        WindowsFeature Web-Client-Auth
        {
            Name    = "Web-Client-Auth"
            Ensure  = "Present"
        }
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 fixes in my script to make it work.

I removed the Web-Cert-Auth feature install, because Web-Cert-Auth is for IIS certificate mapping (which I don't need). Windows Feature Web-Client-Auth is for AD client certificate mapping, which I need.

Then I added this inline script:

```
# (Active Directory) Client Certificate Mapping Authentication should be enabled 
        Script EnableClientCertificateAuthentication
        {
            GetScript = {
                Return @{
                    Result = [string]$((Get-WebConfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication).enabled)
                }
            }

            TestScript = {
                If ((Get-WebConfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication).enabled) {
                    Write-Verbose "ClientCertificateAuthentication is on"
                    Return $true
                } Else {
                      Write-Verbose "ClientCertificateAuthentication is off"
                    Return $false
                }
            }

            SetScript = {
                Write-Verbose "Enabling ClientCertificateAuthentication"
                Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication -name enabled -value true -PSPath IIS:\
            }

            DependsOn = "[WindowsFeature]Web-Client-Auth"
        }
```